# remove navigator in file in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

how do I remove this navigator in a the file view in vs code? thanks!

[image: e i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "breadcrumbs". Search for that in the settings UI, or add this to settings.json:

```
  "breadcrumbs.filePath": "off"
```